# Type error when loading a BERT-based keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

In one Colab Notebook:

```
regression_bert_model.save(model_dir)
```

In another notebook:

```
sciBert_reg_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_dir)
```

Gives me the following error stack:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/type_spec.py in _deserialize(cls, serialization)
    432       A `TypeSpec` of type `cls`.
    433     """
--> 434     return cls(*serialization)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable  # trace-all-classes
    435 
    436   # === Operators ===

TypeError: VariableSpec.__init__() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```